# jQuery .hover requires double click in order to work on Safari iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following js:

```
$(".t-gallery a").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).append("<div class='cover'><i class='fa fa-search-plus'></i></div>");
    },
    function () {
        $('div', this).remove(".cover");
    }
    );
```

Basically it adds a cover to an image (when hovering from pc) and then it opens the gallery, the problem is that using this js requires the users to double click in order to open the gallery if they're using Safari on an iPhone or iPad, how can I possibly fix this issue?

Comment: iOS doesn't has a pointer and, therefor can't have a hover effect

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors in your code... $('div', this).remove('.cover'); should really be $(this).find('.cover').remove();

Comment: That's not incorrect, it's called [selector context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context). Same thing `.find()` uses.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to simulate `hover` on a device with no pointing device (mouse...). You need to come with a UX that better supports phones/ tablets... You should check [javascript tough events](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml), and use them :-)

Comment: yeah I know and that's why I want to replace the .hover , but I don't know what's the correct syntax in order to detect the click on iOS

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $(".t-gallery a").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).append("<div class='cover'><i class='fa fa-search-plus'></i></div>");
    },
    function () {
        $('div', this).remove(".cover");
    }
    ).on('touchstart',function(){
    $(this).trigger('click');
  });
```

Comment: try:
`.on('touchstart',function(){
    $(this).trigger('click');
  });
`